# About the necessity of the field-theoretic viewpoint

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, second-quantization

## What I've been taught

Fields arise naturally in the following way: first, we realize that to describe a system of many (possibly identical) particles is best described by the introduction of ladder operators $(a_p,a_p^\dagger)$ for each momentum state $p$, thus giving rise to Fock space. What we have obtained is then essentially a harmonic oscillator with an infinite number of degrees of freedom; pushing the analogy further, we may treat particles as modes of oscillation ("excitations") of some field (such as the electromagnetic field) via the correspondence

$$ c_n\to (a_ne^{-i\omega_n t}+a_n^\dagger e^{i\omega_n t}) $$

in the Lagrangian for an oscillating system $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}(\dot c_n)^2-\frac{1}{2}\omega_n^2 c_n^2\right)$, to be implemented in some operator $$\Phi(x)\sim\int dp\ a(p)e^{-ipx}+a^\dagger(p)e^{ipx}.$$

In the Fock formalism, this is interpreted as the possibility to create or destruct particles with four-momentum $p$, described by plane wave functions at a certain point $x=(t,x,y,z)$ in four-dimensional spacetime.

As these operators describe the dynamics of a particle, they must be the extrema of an appropriate action $S[\Phi]$ arising from some Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$. To fully quantize the theory one finally has to require that the usual quantum-mechanical commutation relations in the Hamiltonian formulation (i.e. $-i$ for momentum and position) between $\Phi$ and the conjugate field $\Pi=\delta \mathcal{L}/\delta \dot\Phi$. Relativistic covariance of all equations involving fields is then nicely recovered by requiring the Lagrangian to transform as a scalar under the action of the Lorentz group.

This is what I was taught last semester, and it makes sense. By the discussion above we have also implictly managed to avoid the thorny issue of dealing with the fact that while in QM position is prescribed to be a self-adjoint operator, time is a mere scalar; in QFT they have both become inputs of operator-valued real functions and thus are on the same footing, as it should be from a relativistic POV.

## A different derivation?

I've been reading Schwartz' QFT book and found the following line of reasoning. Under the trasformations allowed in the Poincaré group $\text{ISO}(1,3)$, the states of a particle as described by its set of quantum numbers are mixed among themselves. In a precise sense, if states transform under the action of $\text{ISO}(1,3)$ as $|\psi\rangle\to\mathcal{P}|\psi\rangle$, we call such a set of objects $\psi$ a *representation* (following the convention of naming representations after the vector space on which the target endomorphisms are defined rather than by the actual group homomorphism). Such a representation is *irreducible* if there is no subset of states that are mixed among themselves, and *unitary* if $\mathcal P^\dagger\mathcal P=1$. This is required because matrix elements $\langle\psi_2|\psi_1\rangle\to \langle\psi_2 |\mathcal P^\dagger P|\psi_1\rangle$ should be Poincaré invariant - they are exactly the quantities we are interested in calculating! Thus, the following operative definition of a particle is given:

> Particles transform under unitary irreps of $\text{ISO}(1,3)$.

This is physically significant: by Wigner's theorem, such reps are specified uniquely by a real number/half integer pair $(m, J)$ (mass and spin) and are all *infinite-dimensional*, with $2J+1$ independent components. Once mass and spin have been given, the problem of building an interacting theory lies in embedding these unitary irreps in objects with space-time indexes, i.e. tensor or spinor fields with $4^n$ components.

This is the key to my question. Practically speaking, I can see that the former POV is better suited to guessing the form of the actual fields, while the latter gives us hints for how we should build the Lagrangians. But are these two formulations equally valid, and does one imply the other?

Comment: *Fields arise naturally in the following way...* You seem to be talking about quantum fields. But hopefully you first learned about classical fields, such as in Maxwell’s electromagnetism.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes...

Comment: The second approach just say what fundamental particles are (they transform under unitary irreducible representations of the Poincar\'e group). The first approach is just the recipe for quantising the theory and can also be applied to other areas such as condensed matter physics.